# Powershell has stopped working - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: powershell

I am trying to repair my UI in windows 10 (broken start menu) but in order to do that I need powershell. When I try to run it either through an Administrator cmd line ( or with Run As Admin ), it crashes.

[image]

I have checked the event log and seen:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: PowerShell
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: powershell.exe
P2: 10.0.10586.0
P3: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P4: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P5: mation.Language.PSEnumerableBinder.FallbackConvert
P6: mation.Language.PSEnumerableBinder.FallbackConvert
P7: Pipeli..ution Thread
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:


Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c1d9e7d0-d9c1-11e5-82ea-8019343c6792
Report Status: 262144
Hashed bucket:
```

Finally, I opened an older app called process explorer to see the I/O system calls and see powershell is attempting to access a file/folder that doesn't exist.

[image]

**I am at a loss though as to how to continue... what to run, or reinstall or update. I can't seem to find a solution on the internet currently (unless it escapes my notice).**

Comment: You should ask break/fix questions on superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling WMF5 / 4?

I'd try upgrading to WMF5 production preview (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48729) and see if that fixes the Powershell issue.

Else, I'd try a reinstall of WMF4 (as the repair might be trying to run an older version of powershell).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried that but it is already windows 10 and it doesn't want to re-install. I think formatting is the only fix :(